# Make a windows Extension handler for custom icons in C#

Tags: c#, windows

I want to handle a file extension icon by dll and give icon according to file contents in Windows Explorer (something like thumbnail icons for PSD files. Photoshop handles .psd extension and generates thumbnail for each file)

I made a dll in C# that can handle `Load` and `GetIconLocation` functions well. It seems Windows should call the `Extract` function after `GetIconLocation` but it won't!

Interface:

```
   [ComVisible(true), ComImport, Guid("000214eb-0000-0000-c000-000000000046"),
    InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)]
   public interface IExtractIcon
   {
        [PreserveSig]
        uint GetIconLocation(int uFlags, IntPtr szIconFile, int cchMax, IntPtr piIndex, UIntPtr pwFlags);

        //[PreserveSig]
        //uint GetIconLocation(uint uFlags, IntPtr szIconFile, uint cchMax, IntPtr piIndex, UIntPtr pwFlags);
        [PreserveSig]
        uint Extract(string pszFile, uint nIconIndex, ref IntPtr phiconLarge,ref IntPtr phiconSmall, uint nIconSize);
    }
```

And functions:

```
    public uint Load(string pszFileName, uint dwMode)//Using IPersistFile
    {
        icon_File = System.IO.Path.Combine(System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location), "Icon.bmp");
        tip = "My tool-tip";
        Logger.WriteLog("Load :"+pszFileName+" , "+dwMode.ToString());

        return S_OK;

    }

    public uint GetIconLocation(int uFlags, IntPtr szIconFile, int cchMax, IntPtr piIndex, UIntPtr pwFlags)//Using IExtractIcon and IPersistFile.Load
    {
            try
            {
                IconHandlerReturnFlags Flags;

                Flags = IconHandlerReturnFlags.PerClass | IconHandlerReturnFlags.DontCache | IconHandlerReturnFlags.NotFilename;
                pwFlags = (UIntPtr)Flags;

                Logger.WriteLog("GetIconLocation...");
                return S_OK;
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Logger.WriteLog("GetIconLocation " + e.Message);
                return S_FALSE;
            }
        }


        public uint Extract(string pszFile, uint nIconIndex, ref IntPtr phiconLarge,ref IntPtr phiconSmall, uint nIconSize)//Using IExtractIcon 
        {

                Logger.WriteLog("Extract...");
    // other code...
}
```

`Load` function works correctly and gives correct filename. Also `GetIconLocation` works.
But after return S_OK value Extract won't exec...:(

This is the log after view two `.myf` files icon in Windows Explorer

```
Load : C:\**********1.Myf , 0
GetIconLocation...
Load : C:\**********2.Myf , 0
GetIconLocation...
Load : C:\**********1.Myf , 0
GetIconLocation...
GetIconLocation...
Load : C:\**********1.Myf , 0
GetIconLocation..
```

(Sometimes two `GetIconLocation` call without `Load`)

Please someone help me....

Answer (score 0):

it may help you answer my question:(from microsoft site...)

Implementing the IExtractIcon
Interface
After the interface is initialized, the
Shell uses the handler's IExtractIcon
interface to request the appropriate icon.
The interface has two methods:
IExtractIcon::GetIconLocation and
IExtractIcon::Extract .
Icons are identified by their location in
the file system. The
IExtractIcon::GetIconLocation method
is called to request this information. Set
the szIconFile parameter to the file
name. If there is more than one icon in
the file, set piIndex to the icon's index.
Assign appropriate values to the two
flag variables. If you do not want to
specify a file name, or if you do not
want the Shell to extract the icon, set the
GIL_NOTFILENAME flag in the pwFlags
parameter. You do not need to assign a
value to szIconFile, but the handler
must provide icon handles when the
Shell calls IExtractIcon::Extract .
If you return a file name, the Shell
normally attempts to load the icon from
its cache. To prevent the loading of a
cached icon, set the GIL_DONTCACHE
flag in the pwFlags parameter. If a
cached icon is not loaded, the Shell then
calls
IExtractIcon::Extract to request the
icon handle.
If a file and index were specified by
IExtractIcon::GetIconLocation , they
are passed to IExtractIcon::Extract in
the
pszFile and nIconIndex parameters,
respectively. If a file name is provided,
your handler can return S_FALSE to
have the Shell extract the icon.
Otherwise, your handler must extract or
otherwise produce large and small
icons, and assign their HICON handles to
the phiconLarge and phiconSmall
parameters. The Shell adds the icons to
its cache to expedite subsequent calls to
the handler.